# Structure of ViewController / UIViews

Tags: ios

What is the best way to achieve a structure like Pokémon Go does with their menus and items. [Link to pic](http://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/styles/larger/public/article_images/2016/07/pokemon-go-buy-pokecoins-screens-01.jpeg). If I have the map etc in a view controller, should the "menu" be another view controller or just a UIView that I show/hide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view hierarchy of the Pokemon Go class is unique.  I believe that the initial menu that is displayed from clicking the Pokemon Ball is just a UIView over the view controller, since you can still see the map view controller and animations of moving in the background.

The screen that appears when you click one of those menu items is most likely a new view controller.  This new view controller is pushed onto the navigation stack without any animation and when you close that menu, the view controller that was presented is dismissed, as well as the UIView menu from the initial view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!